# Is Possible to print tamil characters in raw bt using javascript - ESCPOS Package

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to print tamil characters in thermal printer. and getting '????' or any other garbage character. code I am using is as follows.

```
const escpos = require('escpos');
const printer = new escpos.Printer(device, options);

device.open(function(){
  printer
  .font('a')
  .align('ct')
  .style('bu')
  .size(1, 1)
  .text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
  .text('நன்றி')
  .barcode('1234567', 'EAN8')
  .table(["One", "Two", "Three"])
  .tableCustom([ 
    { text:"Left", align:"LEFT", width:0.33 },
    { text:"Center", align:"CENTER", width:0.33},
    { text:"Right", align:"RIGHT", width:0.33 }
  ]) 
  .qrimage('https://github.com/song940/node-escpos', function(err){
    this.cut();
    this.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: what does printer `options` object contain?